# NaN loss for LSTM model for integer sequence learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am training a LSTM model to predict the next number of a integer sequence. My input is of the form

```
Id  Sequence
3   1,3,13,87,1053,28576,2141733,508147108,402135275365,1073376057490373,9700385489355970183,298434346895322960005291,31479360095907908092817694945,11474377948948020660089085281068730
7   1,2,1,5,5,1,11,16,7,1,23,44,30,9,1,47,112,104,48,11,1,95,272,320,200,70,13,1,191,640,912,720,340,96,15,1,383,1472,2464,2352,1400,532,126,17,1,767,3328,6400,7168,5152,2464,784,160,19,1,1535,7424
8   1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,32,40,64,80,128,160,256,320,512,640,1024,1280,2048,2560,4096,5120,8192,10240,16384,20480,32768,40960,65536,81920,131072,163840,262144,327680,524288,655360,1048576,1310720,2097152
11  1,8,25,83,274,2275,132224,1060067,3312425,10997342,36304451,301432950,17519415551,140456757358,438889687625,1457125820233,4810267148324,39939263006825,2321287521544174,18610239435360217
13  111,112,211,134,321,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
15  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,5,5,1,1,1,1,11,5,5,11,5,1,1,1,1,5,23,5,23,5,5,1,1,1,1,21,5,39,5,5,39,5,21,5,1,1,1,1,5,1,17,1,17,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,31,5,5,29,1,1,29,1,5
```

and my code is as follows:

```
def parse_fake(train):
    final_set = []
    for i in range(len(train)):
        x = []
        x1 = list(np.array(train.iloc[i].split(","), dtype = np.float))
        prefix = x1[:-1]
        suffix = x1[-1]
        x = [0,prefix,suffix]
        final_set.append(x)
    return final_set



dataset = pd.read_csv('G:/Python/integer_sequencing/sample.csv', index_col = 'Id')
train_data= parse_fake(dataset.Sequence) 
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=['sid', 'prefix', 'suffix'])
df['suffix'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
#df.to_csv('testcsv.csv')
#print(df)
maxlen = int(round(df.prefix.apply(len).min()))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = skcv.train_test_split(df['prefix'].values, df['suffix'].values, test_size=.1)

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, dtype='float', maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, dtype='float', maxlen=maxlen)
print(X_train.shape)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape + (1,))
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape + (1,))

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape= (maxlen, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape= (maxlen, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape= (maxlen, 1)))
model.summary()

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
#print(model.evaluate(X_test_rshp, y_test))
```

Everytime I try to train my model it gives me NaN loss. How do I resolve it ?
The sample dataset can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kcYH814KDuxTVvlfT-UlsIEqlCYzwmZN).
Can you explain why a NaN loss occurs? And what steps should I take or corrections should I make to my code to avoid it?

Comment: You've got numbers waaay bigger than int64. I don't think it will ever work.

Comment: So is there any way around it? Please it's my class project and I need to find results to it.

Comment: The first thing would be trying with smaller numbers, try limiting the values to 10000, for instance, and check if you can make it work. Does your project need number that big?

Comment: I tried for 4 elements per sequence. So on the first epoch my accuracy comes to be 0.0398 but the loss is still NaN

Comment: Just make sure CUDA, CuDNN , Keras and tensorflow/theano (depending upon the backend you use) are compatible and your drivers are updated. It may not solve your problem but I have  had a similar problem and it was due to a version mismatch between tensorflow and cudnn. Also as the first comment stated you still need to make sure your variables fit the precision you use.